# javascript-var value displaying NaN randomly?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am running into a strange issue. I am building a online store, and have displayed my products as so:

```
var products = {
'Box1':{
    'price' : 10,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'Box2':{
    'price': 15,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'Clothes1':{
    'price': 20,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'Clothes2':{
    'price': 30,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'Jeans':{
    'price': 50,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'Keyboard':{
    'price': 20,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'KeyboardCombo':{
    'price': 40,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'Box2':{
    'Mice': 20,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'PC1':{
    'price': 350,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'PC2':{
    'price': 400,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'PC3':{
    'price': 300,
    'quantity' : 10
},
'Tent':{
    'price': 100,
    'quantity' : 10
},
};
```

I also have declared a global variable

```
 var priceTotal = 0;
```

I have an addtocart function that is called when i click "Add" button on a product. This is working as intended. My function looks like this:

```
function addToCart(productName) {
  //var total = 5;
  cart[productName]++;
  products[productName].quantity --;
  priceTotal = priceTotal + products[productName].price;
  var element = document.getElementById("cartTotal");
  element.innerHTML = "CartTotal($"+priceTotal+")";
```

}

For whatever reason, everything is working as i want it too, except for when i add Box2. Whenever i click on add for box2, my priceTotal displays NaN, no matter the previous value for priceTotal. I have tried changing the value for price to different numbers, but it is still occuring. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Is there an apparent error here or do i need to show more of my code?

Thanks

Comment: that mean either `priceTotal` or `products[productName].price` is returning `NaN`... add a console log to see which is becoming `NaN` - Add `console.log('addToCart', productName, priceTotal, products[productName].price)` before `priceTotal = priceTotal + products[productName].price;`

Comment: You have `Box2` twice (8th) in your product list and the second have no price but a Mice

Comment: thanks so much anonymous0day. not sure how i missed that

Comment: You are welcome ! i am glad to help you !

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely you're accidentally adding ***box 2*** twice, the second time with "Mice" instead of "price," so the priceTotal value will be off.